# Where is IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator.ConfigureJsonSerializer in version 8.0.3 in Masstransit RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

We upgraded from Masstransit 7.0.6 to 8.0.3

Previously we were configuring `ConfigureJsonSerializer`. But this seems removed from version 8.0.3. Source code below

```
x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
{
    cfg.Host(Config.GetValue<string>("RabbitMQ:Host"), "/", h =>
    {
        h.Username(Config.GetValue<string>("RabbitMQ:Username"));
        h.Password(Config.GetValue<string>("RabbitMQ:Password"));
    });

    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);

    cfg.ConfigureJsonSerializer(settings => { settings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include; return settings; });
});
```

[image]

How do we replace `ConfigureJsonSerializer` and `DefaultValueHandling` ?

I see there is

```
cfg.UseJsonSerializer();
cfg.ConfigureJsonSerializerOptions(options => options.DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.???);
```

would this be the correct replacement and which `DefaultIgnoreCondition` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you [follow the upgrade guide](https://masstransit-project.com/getting-started/upgrade-v6.html), you can see that Newtonsoft is no longer the default JSON serializer. The method you pointed out above was renamed to `ConfigureNewtonsoftJsonSerializer` and is only in the separate Newtonsoft assembly.

If you want to configure System.Text.Json to include default values, you can configure those options using:

```cs
cfg.ConfigureJsonSerializerOptions(options => 
{
    options.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.Never;
    return options;
}
```